# PHP/MYSQL Check database for enum value?

Tags: php, mysql, enums

I am trying to use MySQL to check if an enum value 'form1_completed' in my table 'supplier_session' = 1

So If 'form1_completed' is 1 where the 'session_number' = '12345678' then I want to echo div 1 and if it is 0 I want to echo div2 instead.

my table looks like this:

Table Name = 'supplier_session'

```
Id   |     form1_completed    |    session_number
1                 1 (enum)         12345678
2                 0 (enum)         145456
```

can someone please show me where I am going wrong with this? I am brand new to MySQL and I am getting this error:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden\ssa\suppliers\dashboard.php on line 24

and it is only ever displaying div2.

```
<?php include("include/config.php");

$sql = "SELECT form1_completed FROM supplier_session WHERE supplier_number = '12345678'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div 1>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<div 2>';
}
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if($row['form1_completed']==1){   
echo '<div 1>';
    }
 else {
    echo '<div 2>';
}
}
```

Comment: this gives me the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden\ssa\suppliers\dashboard.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you right. Which fields are in your table supplier_session? Because with that query you get all entries of the column form1_completed from the table.

So there should be with that code as many  outputs as form1_completed entries are. Only when there is no line at all with a form1_completed, then there will be a  output.

BTW: IS `<div 1>` or `<div 2>` even a valid html tag?

Comment: I have updated my question with the table info for you

Comment: In that case your query seems to give no result. The type of session_number is an int or a char/varchar? If it is the last case then replace the = with LIKE and put your digits in quotes like '12345678'

Comment: my session_number is a int(255) value

Comment: change your SQL-query to `SELECT form1_completed FROM supplier_session WHERE session_number = 12345678`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer,

```
<?php include("include/config.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM supplier_session";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if($row['questionaire']==1){   
echo 'hello';
    }
 else {
    echo 'bye';
}
}
}
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```